# Is this how to make a keyword finder/density check?

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a relatively big block of text and am wanting to find the most common keywords within it and calculate the density of these keywords.  The way that I have thought of seems as though it could be slow or performance demanding and difficult:

Iterate over each word in the block of text.
Find all the same matches for each of these words
Count the total matches for each of these words
Take say the top 5 most matches and then calculate their density relative to total block.
output results

Is there any easy quick better way of doing this using jquery?

Comment: Is density defined as % of the text?

Comment: yes you would divide by total words then multiply by 100

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var text = "Lorem ipsum ...";

var word_list = text.split(/\W+/); // Split the text into words.

var counts = {};#
Allocate a dictionary

for (var i = 0; i < word_list.length; ++i) {
    var word = word_list[i];
    counts[word] = (counts[word] || 0) + 1; // Increment count by one.
}

var densities = {};

for (word in counts) {
    densities[word] = parseFloat((counts[word] / word_list.length) * 100).toFixed(2); // Calculates all the densities percentage.
}
```

All that's left is to get the most frequent ones.

You may want to change how the text is split into keywords, or filter very common/short words out. Right now "it's" ends up split into 'it', 's'. This may not be what you want.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help everyone I have a better understanding of how to approach it

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this with a varying sliding window. Every time a blank space `" "` is encountered, increment a word counter, and add the current word to a bucket. If the bucket contains that word, add a counter to the bucket. Once the whole text is parsed, get the bucket with the max count. Output the bucket word, divide the bucket count by max count.